# Telegram Bot Api Save Images

Tags: python, image, download, bots, telegram

I Want to Build a Bot, Bot will handle messages photo and Caption (text) form sender Then Save To Local Computer,

Messages containing :

1. Images / Photo
2. Text As Photo Caption or description

How to get text value was send to myBots?

I want use it at File Name to save in local drive, mycode work but images was saved with {file.id}.JPG

Here My Code :

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'audio'])
    def handle_docs_photo(message):
        raw = message.photo[0].file_id
        path = raw+".jpg"
        file_info = bot.get_file(raw)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        with open("D://BotBagus//Images//"+path,'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
            bot.reply_to(message, "Images Was Saved Sir 
    "+message.from_user.first_name+"With Caption : " +message.text)
    bot.polling()
    print ("BOT Running")
```

Comment: Why Pasted Code not write new line ?

Comment: [SOLVED] i use message.caption to get description of Photos